# bootstrap datepicker invalid date issue when i click date twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker and I got invalid date issue in a specific case. If I click today date it works fine but when I click the same date again it gives out invalid date issue.

Same is the case for all the dates as I have seen other plugins where I can't find this issue.

html:
    `<input id="dp1" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  placeholder="Data CheckIn">`

javascript:

```
$("#dp1").datepicker({
    format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
    viewMode: 'days',
    todayHighlight: true 
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    var a = $('#dp1').datepicker('getDate');
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
    alert(a);
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FTpYk/321/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FTpYk/321/

Comment: This is because you are deselecting the selected date. See the icon colors yellow(deselect) and blue(select). When you click on currently selected date it will obviously return invalid as it is getting unselected/toggled.

Comment: It does look like a bug in the plugin- like the `toggleActive` option (which should default to false anyway) is not working. I did try manually setting it and still no change in behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an effort of a day I solved issue by myself by doing a little change in plugin.

In bootstrap-datepicker.js  method  _toggle_multidate  line no 1024 has been commented.

```
else if (ix !== -1)
{
    //this.dates.remove(ix);
}
```

and it will work like a charm. I hope this can help.

Please try and do let me know if this case solve your issue
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
var currentDate;
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
    viewMode: 'days',
    todayHighlight: true

    // currently picked date
  }).on('show', function() {
    currentDate = $(this).val();
  })
  // if no date picked replace with previous date
  .on('changeDate', function(ev) {


    if ($(this).val() === '' || $(this).val() === null) {
      $(this).val(currentDate).datepicker('update');
    }
    var a = $('#dp1').datepicker('getDate');
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
    alert(a);

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use delegate, it does work fine

```js
$("body").delegate('.date' ,'focusin', function() {
     $(this).datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         viewMode: 'days',
         todayHighlight: true
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not an issue.When you click first time it will set the selected date on input when you click again on same date again so it will deselect that date.

Comment: Now this is a bug in plugin if you see all other datepicker plugin behavior you will find an issue and on the other hand its not appropriate as per user  perspective.

Comment: Then how could be a valid question is this, For fulfilling our needs we need to edit/modify or do somethings in order to achieve requirement. That's why I've added an answer.